# How to add/limit 2 decimals .00 in the input field of type number in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

Angular 7 - I'm trying to add .00 to the input field, this field is limited to accept only numbers and that works fine, however, I'd like to be able to add .00 in the same editable input field as soon as the user navigates to a different field in the form. I've added pipes as `[(ngModel)]="appform.budgetvalue | number: '1.2-2'"` but it fails to load. I've added `(change)="addDecimal($event)"` near the end but the method fails to trigger, some stackoverflow articles are suggesting to create a custom directive but unsure if that is the correct approach, based on the snippet below can some please suggest an approach, any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6"
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <input name="budgetvalue" class="form-control" required digitOnly
        decimal="true" decimalSeparator="." decimalDigitLimit="2" placeholder="0.00"
        pattern="[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?" isValidMoney
        [(ngModel)]="appform.budgetvalue" #budgetvalue="ngModel">
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="(budgetvalue.touched)">
      <div *ngIf="!budgetvalue?.valid">
        <small class="text-danger">Please provide valid budget amount</small>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You could use a component mask to do that (there are a lot out there) or create you own. But I suggest you use type="text" instead of number.

Comment: it sort of has to be a number as this value gets stored in the database. limiting the entry seems like a good approach as supposed to accepting text and then writing code to filter out non-numerical values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple ways I can think of:

```
<input name="" ... (blur)="transform()" />
...
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {}

  decimal = "0";

  transform() {
    this.decimal = this.decimalPipe.transform(this.decimal, '1.2-2');
  }
}
```

One caveat is that transform pipe returns a string.
I've written [this directive](https://gist.github.com/ihorbond/51768559d01949b09d2aef646fcebe06) I've used in a past for reactive form or [this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/decimal-directive) for template

2. `<input [value]="appform.budgetvalue | number: '1.2-2'"/>` - this however probably doesnt work the way you expect but might give you some ideas

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you by any chance have sample code or reference on how to implement it?

Comment: sorry just realized it was for a reactive form but you are using template syntax.. however you could prob still use it if instead of NgControl you inject ElementRef and Renderer2 to update input's value. I'll see if I can put together stackblitz real quick

Comment: No problem :) any code sample would be very helpful thank you.

Comment: here, try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/decimal-directive very important to use Renderer2  to manipulate value to avoid XSS attacks

Comment: Thanks again, appreciate your help. I'm facing 2 issues with my code snippet above, maybe you can help. 1. no matter where I place my `change()` or `blur()` method they don't seem to fire at all not sure what I'm missing 2. I've tried - `parseFloat(String(this.budgvalue)).toFixed(2);` it successfully adds 2 decimals as I wanted but then it fails to convert the string back to number as the casting takes away the decimal points. any thoughts?

Comment: about 1st issue it looks like you have some other directives on that input so maybe one of them catches the event and doesn't let it to bubble up. what if just do <input [(ngModel)]="appform.budgetvalue" (blur)="transform()" /> does transform get called ? about 2nd issue yeah, it's a pain cause .toFixed() also returns a string but I think the directive should get you what you need as it only transforms the "face" value so the underlying budgetvalue shouldnt be affected the only issue remains is when you need to persist data to db...I just pass value as formatted string and convert in API

Comment: thangs again. yep i tried just that earlier `<input [(ngModel)]="appform.budgetvalue" (blur)="transform()" />` and transform isn't getting called any ideas?. the issue with both directive and .toFixed is the string as I do have to save this value into SQL DB and the API is currently expecting a number, not a string, is there a way to achieve the end result with it being a number so i don't have to change the API?

Comment: The directive worked! thanks again for helping out.